# Transistor Collector Current comparison between different Suppliers

Tags: transistors, pnp

I have a PCB which is currently using a pnp transistor with a Collector Current of 200 mAdc.

I would like to use an alternative transistor with the same electrical characteristics; except that the Collector Current of the alternative is 500 mAdc.

I am wondering if there would be any risk to use the alternative transistor with the higher collector current?  Or if it's only a risk if the alternative transistor's collector current was less than 200 mAdc.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Do you mean that the PNP has a maximum rated current of 200 mA? How do you know that the alternative has the same electrical characteristics? Have you compared data sheet details precisely? When replacing components you should review the schematic.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's referring to the maximum rating.  "Maximum Rating, Collector Current: -500mA".  I also reviewed the other aspects of the datasheet and they are the same.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment: *When replacing components you should review the schematic*. Reason: sometimes it's the invisible ink in the data sheet comparison that makes a data sheet comparison foolish.

Comment: We need links to the datasheets of the two transistors to properly answer this.

Answer (score 1):

If the alternative transistor has exactly the same characteristics except for a higher rated collector current, then you should be fine to use the alternative.

I'd be a little curious as to why the collector current rating was so much higher, you don't usually get something for nothing, I'd normally expect to see something else degrade. Is the collector current rated under the same conditions? Are specifications that are guaranteed for one part typical in the other? Is it rated by a third party reseller rather than the manufacturer?

It's possible the alternative is in a cooler package, or built using a higher performance process, or just intended for a higher specification role. There might be entirely benign reasons for the higher rating.